Where does the spectral decomposition $\mathcal M=\sum_k \lambda_k u_k\otimes v_k$ for a quantum channel come from?
I'm currently watching a lecture where the lecturer talks about unistochastic maps $\mathcal{M}$ that map $d\times d $ dimensional operators to other $d\times d$ dimensional operators.
He then goes on defining the right and left eigenvectors of this channel as
$$\mathcal{M}u_k = \lambda_k u_k$$
and
$$v_k \mathcal{M} = \lambda_k v_k$$
respectively. Here $k=0,\dots d^2 -1$.
With these he then writes down the spectral decompostion of $\mathcal{M}$ as $$\mathcal{M} = \sum_k \lambda_k u_k \otimes v_k$$
and I don't really have an idea where this is coming from.
My thought so far was that $\mathcal{M}$ is not really the channel itself but its $d^2 \times d^2$ dimensional Choi representation. Then the $u_k$ and $v_k$  are $d^2$ dimensional vectorized operators and the term $u_k \otimes v_k$ may essentially correspond to $\mid u_k\rangle\langle v_k\mid$ which would then look more like the usual form of the spectral decomposition I know of since I'm accustomed to write it like
$$\mathcal{M} = \sum_k \lambda_k \mid k\rangle\langle k\mid$$
However, I am really not sure if I'm right about that. In my search I saw some other keywords like the operator Schmidt decomposition but I'm also cannot see how it is connected to this.
Would really appreciate any sort of help on this or some guidance to a good reference which maybe talks about this topic, thank you!

tl;dr: I think that the lecturer uses the outer product notation meaning their $u\otimes v$ is not a Kronecker product but rather the ket-bra $|u\rangle\langle v|$. I'll of course explain where my suspicion is coming from down below.

The following is taken from Michael Wolf's lecture notes on quantum channels, Section 2.3 and page 92 ff. to be precise. However, the form you asked about is not exclusive to channels at all.
First, we have to go to the super-operator of $\mathcal M$ with respect to vectorization, denoted ${\rm vec}$:

Given any linear map $\mathcal M:\mathbb C^{d\times d}\to\mathbb C^{d\times d}$ let $\widehat{\mathcal M}\in\mathbb C^{d^2\times d^2}$ be the unique matrix such that ${\rm vec}(\mathcal M(X))=\widehat{\mathcal M}{\rm vec}(X)$ for all $X\in\mathbb C^{d\times d}$.

If the matrix $\widehat{\mathcal M}$ is diagonalizable then the left and right eigenvectors of $\widehat{\mathcal M}$ are bi-orthogonal in the following sense:

Lemma. Given $\widehat{\mathcal M}\in\mathbb C^{d^2\times d^2}$ diagonalizable there exist bases $\{u_k\}_k,\{v_k\}_k$ of $\mathbb C^{d^2}$ which satisfy $\langle v_j|u_k\rangle=\delta_{jk}$ for all $j,k=1,\ldots,d^2$ such that $\widehat{\mathcal M}=\sum_k\lambda_k|u_k\rangle\langle v_k|$ where $\{\lambda_k\}_k$ are the eigenvalues of $\widehat{\mathcal M}$ in some order. In particular, the desired left- and right-eigenvector relations $\widehat{\mathcal M}|u_k\rangle=\lambda_k|u_k\rangle$ and $\langle v_k|\widehat{\mathcal M}=\lambda_k\langle v_k|$ hold.

Proof. We start from any diagonalization $\widehat{\mathcal M}=SDS^{-1}$ with $S\in\mathbb C^{d^2\times d^2}$ invertible and $D\in\mathbb C^{d^2\times d^2}$ diagonal. Define $|u_k\rangle:=S|k\rangle$ as well as $|v_k\rangle:=(S^{-1})^\dagger|k\rangle$; these are bases because $S$ is bijective.
Writing $D=\sum_k\lambda_k|k\rangle\langle k|$ yields
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\mathcal M}&=\sum_k\lambda_kS|k\rangle\langle k|S^{-1}\\
&=\sum_k\lambda_kS|k\rangle((S^{-1})^\dagger|k\rangle)\\
&=\sum_k\lambda_k|u_k\rangle(|v_k\rangle)^\dagger=\sum_k\lambda_k|u_k\rangle\langle v_k|\,.
\end{align*}
Most importantly, for all $j,k$
$$
\langle v_j|u_k\rangle=\langle j|S^{-1}S|k\rangle=\langle j|k\rangle=\delta_{jk}
$$
which shows
$$
\widehat{\mathcal M}|u_k\rangle=\sum_j\lambda_j|u_j\rangle\langle v_j|u_k\rangle=\sum_j\lambda_j|u_j\rangle\delta_{jk}=\lambda_k|u_k\rangle
$$
and, analogously, $\langle v_k|\widehat{\mathcal M}=\lambda_k\langle v_k|$ for all $k$. $\square$
With this one can identify the vectors $u_k,v_k$ with square matrices $U_k,V_K\in\mathbb C^{d\times d}$ (via vectorization, i.e. $u_k={\rm vec}(U_k)$ and similarly for $v_k$); these are still bi-orthogonal in the sense that ${\rm tr}(V_j^\dagger U_k)=\delta_{jk}$, and our lemma implies that $\mathcal M$ takes the form
$$
\mathcal M=\sum_k\lambda_k{\rm tr}(V_k^\dagger(\cdot))U_k\,.\tag1
$$
At this point a word of caution: recall that everything we did so far crucially relied on the assumption that $\widehat{\mathcal M}$ was diagonalizable.
Now there of course exist square matrices which are not diagonalizable and—even worse—not every quantum channel is diagonalizable either. So there exist channels which cannot be written like (1) because they admit less than $d^2$ left/right eigenvectors; however, most channel unsurprisingly can be written in this way.
At this point we can finally try to match this spectral decomposition with what was presented in your lecture.
I can think of two scenarios as to what the lecturer intended to do, although the first one is more likely in my opinion:

The lecturer in question implicitly identified $\mathcal M$ with $\widehat{\mathcal M}$ and they simply used the notation $u\otimes v$ (outer product) instead of $|u\rangle\langle v|$. At least from my experience the outer product is more common in mathematics while $\otimes$ in quantum information refers almost exclusively to the Kronecker/tensor product.
The lecturer in question implicitly identified $\mathcal M$ with its Choi matrix $\mathsf C(\mathcal M)$ & the latter is defined as the action of $\mathcal M$ of the first—and not the second—half of a bipartite system. Then the Choi matrix of a "reset map" $X\mapsto{\rm tr}(A^\dagger X)B$ is given by $B\otimes\overline A$ as is readily verified; here $\overline A$ is the entry-wise complex conjugate of $A$. Combining this insight with (1) yields $\mathsf C(\mathcal M)=\sum_k\lambda_kU_k\otimes\overline{V_k}$ which is almost the desired form.


Thank you very much for this really thorough answer, especially for case 1. That gave a much better understanding to where this is coming from. Regarding both cases: I somehow think it is a mix of these two. The thing is, the whole point of this diagonalization task was to calculate a two-point correlation function looking like $$C_{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{d}{\rm tr}(b\mathcal{M}^t(a))$$ where $b$ and $a$ are single site (local) operators.

The interesting thing now is that he writes down this diagonalization form and then says “ok, so $\mathcal{M}$ is vectorized now so you need to be careful. But basically the result to the correlation function is”:
$$C_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_{k}\lambda_{k}^t {\rm tr}(bu_k)  {\rm tr}(a v_k).$$ This, however, would not work if $u_k$ and $v_k$ would still be in their vectorized form, right (also the trace only factorizes for the tensor product I guess)? So I guess he maybe switches in his head from case 1 to 2 in order to justify the final result.

I thought about it again: I guess the correlation function above, which was written on the blackboard, is just wrong then. I guess it should be: $$C_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_k \lambda_{k}^t {\rm tr}(bu_k){\rm tr}(a \bar{v}_k).$$ But I guess that does not matter too much because we are anyway only interested in $\lambda$.
